# Javascript returning if only one certain checkbox is checked out of a list of possible checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, if-statement

I have a list of checkboxes that require one or two certain boxes to be checked in order to return true, however I am unsure how to go about finding if only the required boxes are checked and no other boxes are.

The HTML for the checkboxes are as follows:

```
<table style="width:135px; height:200px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: -200px;">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f1s1c"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f1s2"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f1s3"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f1s4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f2s1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f2s2"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f2s3"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f2s4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f3s1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f3s2"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f3s3"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="cCorrect1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f4s1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f4s2"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f4s3"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f4s4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see there are many possible chekboxes however in this case only cCorrect1 must be checked in order for the javascript to return true. All the other checkboxes are as classes as I have multiple tables that follow the same structure.

Currently my Javascript returns true if cCorrect1 is checked but obviously also returns true if any other box is also checked along with it.

My Javascript:

```
//Quiz Functions

$("#checkC").click(function(){

if(cCorrect1.checked){

    cCorrect = true;

}else if(cCorrect1.checked == false){

    cCorrect = false;

}

});
```

Would using an array that checks through the checkboxes and finds out when cCorrect1 is checked would work? I think that may be on the right track but I do not know how to go about that.

Any input and help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a way to find the right set of checkboxes (a shared class on all of them, etc.) you can count the number of checked boxes in the list. If it's `1`, and your target box is checked, you're good.

In this example, I added an `id` to the `table` containing the checkboxes to make them easier to find. Removed the style so the table is visible.

```js
$("#checkC").click(function(){

    // the one we want
    var cCorrect1 = $('#cCorrect1');

    // all checked checkboxes in the table
    var checks = $('#boxes input[type=checkbox]:checked');
   
    var cCorrect = cCorrect1.prop('checked') && (checks.length == 1);
  
    alert(cCorrect ? "correct" : "incorrect");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="boxes" >
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f1s1c"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f1s2"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f1s3"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f1s4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f2s1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f2s2"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f2s3"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f2s4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f3s1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f3s2"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f3s3"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="cCorrect1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f4s1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f4s2"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f4s3"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="f4s4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="checkC">check</button>
```

Comment: Perfect example, thank you. For my next table three boxes must be checked so I just included all of the new checkbox variables and and changed checks.length == to 3.

You gave a much simpler way that I thought would be possible and solved the problem.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is create an array of right answers, discover the selected answers per row, and decide if it's "correct" or "incorrect".

You can use this code to return of array of checkboxes state (0 for unchecked, 1 for checked), and decide what to do from there:

```
var $table = this.$('tbody');
        $(".resultBtn").click(function(){
            var outStr = '';
            for(var i= 0,len=$table.children().length;i<len;i++){
                var $tr = $table.children().eq(i);
                outStr += 'row' + (i+1) + ' checked boxes:[';
                for(var j= 0;j<$tr.children().length;j++){
                    var $td = $tr.children().eq(j);
                    if($td.find(':checked').length > 0 ){
                        $td.addClass('selected');
                        outStr += '1,';
                    } else{
                        outStr += '0,';
                    }
                    if(j==$tr.children().length-1) outStr = outStr.substring(0, outStr.length - 1);
                }
                outStr += ']';
            }
            alert(outStr);
        });
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/y3yp4ag1/2/